# deploying rails3 apps with bundler and phusion passenger: .bundle dir not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, passenger, bundler

i am trying to deploy rails3 apps with the latest phusion passenger 2.2.11 and ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01. i am using bundler, but passenger seems to not be able to find the .bundle dir.

error message:

```
git://github.com/rails/rails.git (at master) is not checked out. Please run `bundle install` (Bundler::PathError)
```

where do i install the .bundle? where do i tell passenger which bundle to use?
any hints?

thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

i think the command you are searching for is

```
bundle pack
```

which will move your gems from the .bundle directory to the vendor/cache.

see yehuda katz' posting about bundler workflows on his site: http://yehudakatz.com/2010/02/09/using-bundler-in-real-life/

more information on the bundler directory: you can add in you application.rb file the following line, which will change the bundler dir for phusion passenger:

```
ENV['BUNDLER_HOME']="/home/or-wherever-you-want-to-point-it"
```

Comment: Note that this blog post is out of date (for people seeing this from here on out)

Comment: I had to run `bundle pack --all`. Without the `--all` flag it wouldn't pack GIT/path dependencies. (Using bundler 1.3.0.)

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't need to "pack" your gems.

I've spent a week trying everything. Following ALL of the troubleshooting steps here finally resolved it:

https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/blob/master/ISSUES.md

Good luck!

Comment: Yeah, shouldn't need to, but it's exactly what I had to do in production on Digital Ocean Ubuntu rails appliance. I tried everything in the link you pasted to no avail

Answer (score 2):

Been fighting this one also. I've found that doing a

```
bundle --deployment
```

does the trick. See the post here: [Rails 3: Passenger can't find git gems installed by bundler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605235/rails-3-passenger-cant-find-git-gems-installed-by-bundler)

Seems a bit hacky to me however. Would like to know if this is an issue with Passenger or bundler? Is it version specific, etc...

Answer (score 0):

[This gem bundler site](http://gembundler.com/) said that for deployment you may use:

```
bundle install --deployment
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. It tries to build native extensions and it brings even more pain: make, gcc, toubles with used libs in gcc compilation....

Answer (score 0):

try

```
bundle install vendor/bundler
```

Answer (score 0):

What did helped me exactly on:
1. CentOS 6.x 64bit
2. Bitnami stack bundle with spree 1.3.1

```
cd SPREE_APP_ROOT_AKA_RAILS_ROOT
/opt/spree-1.3.1-0/ruby/bin/bundle install
```

As a result gem appeared in the root. But it's not good. It should go to vendor/cache and other underlying folders.

The I run:

```
/opt/spree-1.3.1-0/ruby/bin/bundle package --all
```

Option **--all** is for packaging "git" gems.

Restart passenger and go on:)