# Ruby on Rails, bundle deployment dreamhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, rack

I ran into some problem with passenger on Dreamhost after installing refinerycms with its blog plugin. The rack just failed without any information about the 
problem, It only said "... please check the server log ... " and a stack trace 
without any message about the error.

After a while trying to reinstall but failed, running in the same problem. I finally have it work by doing 2 steps:

1) bundle install --deployment
==> It now shows the error about the differences in Rack version, my required 1.2.4 but it's 1.2.1 configured.
( I did 'bundle install' before but not solve the problem of rack )

2) I googled and update my Gemfile.lock to 1.2.4
AND IT WORKS ... LIKE MAGIC...

Can someone explain to me :

1. what did "bundle install --deployment" do differently from
   "bundle install" ?
2. What's "Gemfile" and "Gemfile.lock" different ?
3. Any idea why It would work if I do like above ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

1. [Rails 3's "bundle install" and "bundle install --deployment" both work well except the 2nd one just uses more disk space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681329/rails-3s-bundle-install-and-bundle-install-deployment-both-work-well-exce/3681411#3681411)
2. Gemfile keeps track of what gems are necessary and Gemfile.lock also keeps track of all your gems' dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Regarding #3, Dreamhost basically requires rack 1.2.1, which you would normally set by having a line like this in your Gemfile:

```
gem "rack", "=1.2.1"
```

I assume that hacking the version into Gemfile.lock works because it is installed on the system already, so your app is able to load it without any problems.  But it would certainly be better to just specify it in your Gemfile.

Getting rack-based apps running on Dreamhost can be a bit of a trial.  If you continue to have problems, you will probably need to post some more details about your config and any specific errors you're getting.