# Deploying spree on AWS

Tags: github, amazon-web-services, spree, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy on AWS a spree application.
After setting up elastic-beanstalk and adding to
my_project/.ebextensions/ this .config file

```
packages:
  yum:
    git-core: []
container_commands:
  bundle:
    command: "gem install bundle"
  assets:
    command: "bundle exec rake assets:precompile"
  db:
    command: "bundle exec rake db:migrate"
    leader_only: true
```

I use git aws.push to deploy my app, only to get this error message:

> Could not find rake-10.1.0 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

double-checking on my gem set, using 
    bundle show rake 
gives me:

> ... /gems/rake-10.1.0

while looking at the logfile from AWS I find this error:

> sh: git: command not found
>   Git error: command `git clone 'https://github.com/spree/spree.git'

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to ensure that git is installed on the server.

Try creating a file called:

```
.ebextensions/YOUR_APPLICATION_NAME.config
```

which contains

```
packages:
  yum:
    git: []
```

This will install git with yum as part of your deployment.

Another option is to use spree from a gem instead of sourcing it from git.

For more information, check out this [article on the AWS Blog](http://ruby.awsblog.com/post/Tx2AK2MFX0QHRIO/Deploying-Ruby-Applications-to-AWS-Elastic-Beanstalk-with-Git) about deploying Ruby Applications to Elastic Beanstalk.

Comment: That certainly helped. Thanks. More, I installed my gems in vendor/bundle AND precompile store/shared/_print.css

Comment: That works as long as you don't have any gems installed locally. This is a more comprehensive answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13642171/elastic-beanstalk-ruby-rails-need-to-install-git-so-bundle-install-works-but-i