# Installing git through .ebextensions on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: node.js, git, amazon-web-services, npm, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm getting an error deploying to Elastic Beanstalk, because there is no git on the instance. One of the dependencies in my package.json is dependant on a git repository and needs to `git clone`.
Git is not installed on the instances. I tried installing it through .ebextensions .conf file while deploying, through `yum`, but when I ssh into the instance it's not there.

**Question is: what is the correct way to install and have git on a Linux instance running on Elastic Beanstalk before `npm install` is called on that instance?**

Here's the log showing the error:

```
[2015-04-18T09:00:02.815Z] ERROR [1777]  : Command execution failed: Activity failed. (ElasticBeanstalk::ActivityFatalError)
caused by: + /opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py --action npm-install
  npm WARN package.json amity-api-v2@2.0.0 No repository field.
  npm WARN package.json amity-api-v2@2.0.0 No README data
  npm WARN `git config --get remote.origin.url` returned wrong result (https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-document-js-sdk) undefined
  npm WARN `git config --get remote.origin.url` returned wrong result (https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-document-js-sdk) undefined
  npm ERR! git clone https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-document-js-sdk undefined
  npm ERR! git clone https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-document-js-sdk undefined
  npm ERR! Linux 3.14.35-28.38.amzn1.x86_64
  npm ERR! argv "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v0.12.0-linux-x64/bin/node" "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v0.12.0-linux-x64/bin/npm" "--production" "install"
  npm ERR! node v0.12.0
  npm ERR! npm  v2.5.1
  npm ERR! code ENOGIT

  npm ERR! not found: git
  npm ERR!
  npm ERR! Failed using git.
  npm ERR! This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
  npm ERR! Please check if you have git installed and in your PATH.
```

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13642171/elastic-beanstalk-ruby-rails-need-to-install-git-so-bundle-install-works-but-i).

Comment: ...and [here](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/5967)

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen, I have tried including git as a yum package in the .ebextensions con file, tried the second approach with the dependencies as well, still the same.

Comment: Can you try installing Git directly on your Linux instance?

Comment: Yes. It works that way. But I need git to be there if the EB instance is recreated or when new ones are created in that autoscaling group, which I thought could be achieved through .ebextensions

Comment: Don't you have git already installed on the AMI?

Comment: No, there's no git installed on the AMI. I can use custom AMIs with git on them, but the question still stands: what is the right way to install git on the default Elastic Beanstalk EC2 instances?

Comment: My elasticbeanstalk group just started failing to NPM install because no git was found. First error in a almost 6 months, no code changes anywhere - frozen version numbers. Maybe a bug on AWS side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of three ways you could ensure `git`(or any dependency) is installed on the system before `npm install` is run.

1. Define a `preinstall` script in your `package.json` that installs `git` if required.
2. You can add a [script(file)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#customize-containers-format-files), using ebextensions in either the pre-appdeploy hooks directory, or the preinit hooks directory. I would suggest the preinit hook, as that's where the hook for installing packages is. Just set the path of your script to `/opt/ebextensions/hooks/preinit/99_install_git.sh`, or if you want to do in pre-appdeploy, `/opt/ebextensions/hooks/appdeploy/pre/99_install_git.sh`, and make the file executable by using the `mode` field.
3. Using ebextensions to [install a package](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#customize-containers-format-packages).

For your use case, I think #3 is the best option. Kinda late, but I hope you find it useful

Comment: This is helpful, thanks! But the OP says he included git as a yum package in a ```.elasticbeanstalk/*.config``` --which should do what you suggest in #3, correct? So why does EB ignore it?

Comment: @ericpeters0n I have no idea. I've always found beanstalk to be a fickle beast. Could be an intermittent issue with the instance.

Answer (score 25):

If you put a config file in your .ebextensions folder like this:

```
packages:
  yum:
    git: []
```

Make sure the git package is in a config file with a higher execution index then one that actually requires git. It is common to have it in a first config file named: `00-packages.config`.

Comment: this is what I'm using and it works. [aws doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-packages)