# Elastic Beanstalk and Github gem failure to deploy error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, github, elasticsearch, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My Gemfile for my rails app has a gem that I'm pulling off of Github using the following entry;

```
gem 'markable', github: 'chrome/markable'
```

I have a lot of other gems in the Gemfile but if I remove this one line it works fine so clearly this line is the issue.

This is the deploy output:

```
$ eb deploy
Creating application version archive "899e".
Uploading: [##################################################] 100% Done...
INFO: Environment update is starting.                               
INFO: Deploying new version to instance(s).                         
ERROR: [Instance: i-8c21232c] Command failed on instance. Return code: 11 Output: (TRUNCATED)...ps://rubygems.org/...
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
You need to install git to be able to use gems from git repositories. For help
installing git, please refer to GitHub's tutorial at
https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git. 
Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/10_bundle_install.sh failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
INFO: Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
ERROR: Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-8c21232c'. Aborting the operation.
ERROR: Failed to deploy application.
```

How do I get EB to correctly pull that gem or fix it so that this works?

I see other similar questions but they are old at this point and often refer to a `.ebextensions/ruby.config` file which doesn't exist anywhere in my system.

Thoughts?

Comment: Check here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13642171/elastic-beanstalk-ruby-rails-need-to-install-git-so-bundle-install-works-but-i

Comment: As I posted in the original comment though, that's old and I dont have the file they are editing.

Comment: OKay so I added the file and ruby.config file and it seems to deploy now.  Still not working but father along.

Comment: Jason can you please check file in the .ebextensions/ folder ? check the location it should be like .ebextensions/ruby.config

Comment: Yep I added the file and it works now.. thanks!