# Passenger can't find gems in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

Passenger: 5.0.22, Rails: 3.2.22, Capistrano 3.4.0

I built a new server and am trying to deploy a Rails application with Capistrano. Seems that after deployment Passenger can not start the web app because it can not find some gemfiles. After some digging, I found that it is only the ones that are in the user's .gem/ directory that Passenger can not find even though it's in the application's GEM_PATH.

Have read a number of posts on stackoverflow but they all seem to be for older version (2 and 3) of Passenger. Any ideas, anybody?

Comment: Did you tried solutions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605235/rails-3-passenger-cant-find-git-gems-installed-by-bundler)?

Comment: Using `bundle --deployment` has at least changed the error. Now it reports it is not able to "...map segment from shared object - ... vendor/bundle/ruby/extensions/x86_64-linux/mysql2-0.3.20/mysql2/mysql2.so (LoadError)"

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was SELINUX!!! Disabled it and now Passenger finds all the gems. Grrrrr!