# What does this error mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, rubygems, bundler, spree

Just looking for a super simple answer here.

My app returns this :

```
Error message:
    git://github.com/spree/spree.git (at master) is not checked out. Please run `bundle install` (Bundler::GitError)
Exception class:
    PhusionPassenger::UnknownError
Application root:
    /home/shadyfront/webapps/revolting_age/Age-of-Revolt
```

What does that mean, "is not checked out" ?

I have here in my nginx.conf :

```
env    GEM_HOME=/home/shadyfront/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330@revolting_gems;
```

When I perform `bundle show spree`:

```
#> /home/shadyfront/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330@revolt/bundler/gems/spree-1706124f2f94
```

And I have here in my gem env:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.5.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2010-12-23 patchlevel 330) [i686-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/shadyfront/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330@revolting_gems
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/shadyfront/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p330/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/shadyfront/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330@revolting_gems/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/shadyfront/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330@revolting_gems
     - /home/shadyfront/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

bundle install passes everytime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means you don't have the source code for spree checked out from its git repository. Have you run `bundle install` like the error message suggests?

Comment: Yes sir. plenty of times. I'm guessing that when I do though its installing it in one place. And the app is looking for it in another place. I wonder how I can figure out where the app is looking for the gems.. I'll update what I have above

Comment: @Trip: Yeah, you really need to give more information, like the code that actually generates that error message.

Comment: nothing is showing up in my logs. So I posted my gem env, and my nginx.conf. Can you think of anything else to look into?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `bundle pack`? Looks like a similar problem to this question: [deploying rails3 apps with bundler and phusion passenger: .bundle dir not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2494399/deploying-rails3-apps-with-bundler-and-phusion-passenger-bundle-dir-not-found)

Comment: @mattschaffer, it's a mess. The host through me a seperate server to mess with, and I moved all my applications over, and they worked alright. I think the error here stems from a swap in PATH vars I had exported.