# GemNotFound even though gem is installed

Tags: rubygems, bundler

I know that this question has been asked a thousand times before but, in each case, each person's problem seems to have its own unique answer. The specific error I'm getting is this:

> Could not find rest-client-1.6.7 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

But I have `rest-client-1.6.7` installed so I don't know why this is happening.

Any ideas? I'm using Ubuntu and Passenger.

Gemfile: http://pastebin.com/7NpuwBuk

Gemfile.lock: http://pastebin.com/PAz1EC9h

Comment: Can you include your Gemfile and Gemfile.lock file output?

Comment: Updated.             .asdfdsf

Comment: It looks like I might have the wrong version of `rest-client`: I have 1.6.7 but I need 1.4.

Comment: What are you doing that's causing this error? Are you running `bundle install`? Is it when your app tries to load? Are you using RVM or rbenv?

Comment: It's just when I try to load my app in the browser. I'm using RVM. Everything was working fine until I installed the `stripe` gem (http://rubygems.org/gems/stripe) which depends on `rest-client`.

Comment: Have you followed everything in this [guide](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/integration/passenger)?

Comment: Perhaps your Passenger install isn't using / looking for the gems installed by bundler.

Have you tried manually setting your gem path for Passenger (try running 'bundle pack' or setting ENV['BUNDLER_HOME']="/home/or-wherever-you-want-to-point-it" in your application.rb)

Detailed information about these is available at 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2494399/deploying-rails3-apps-with-bundler-and-phusion-passenger-bundle-dir-not-found 

and 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605235/rails-3-passenger-cant-find-git-gems-installed-by-bundler

Comment: @AndrewMarshall I followed this article linked from the guide (http://blog.ninjahideout.com/posts/the-path-to-better-rvm-and-passenger-integration) and that seems to have fixed it. Thanks. If you put that in answer form, I'll accept it.

Comment: @JasonSwett Glad to here! Migrated my comment to an answer `:)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you've followed all the steps in the [RVM & Passenger integration guide](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/integration/passenger). You may wish to also use [`bundle install --deployment`](http://gembundler.com/man/bundle-install.1.html#DEPLOYMENT-MODE) in production.